Resizable div with a maximum initial height
Consider the following resizable div in HTML+CSS:
<!--HTML-->
<div class="mydiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</div>

/* CSS */
.mydiv {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  resize: vertical;
}

If the contents of the div exceed 200px the result is what I want: the height will be limited to 200px, it will have a scrollbar, and it will be resizeable.
However, if the contents are below 200px of height, the above example will force the height to 200px unnecessarily. In this case, I want the height to be the minimum necessary height.
I tried this:
/* CSS */
.mydiv {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  resize: vertical;
}

however this doesn't work, because the max-height applies even when resizing the div with the resize handle, that is, I will never be able to resize it above 200px.
How do I get this to be resizable with no limits, but to have an initial default maximum height? That is, an initial height that is the minimum between a given value and what fits the contents?
Obviously I'm looking for a CSS-only solution. I know how to do this in JavaScript

Are you saying that if the content is less than 200px high you don't want the user to be able to resize it?

@At Haworth no, I'm saying that if the content is less than 200px I don't want the div to be 200px in height. I want it to always be resizable no matter what.

When resizing, the height is set using the style attribute, for example:
<div class="mydiv" style="height: 473px;">Lorem ipsum</div>.
The div whose size is currently being changed can be selected using this attribute.
.mydiv[style*="height"] {
    max-height: unset;
}



.mydiv {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    resize: vertical;
    background-color: green;
}

.mydiv[style*="height"] {
    max-height: unset;
}
<div class="mydiv">large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large content large</div>
<br>
<div class="mydiv">small content</div>




This is genius, thank you!
